# How to stop firefox driver to fire unnecessary mouse over events

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Webdriver 2.21 and Firefox 11.

I have menu bar which populate a drop down menu on mouse over event. When i fire a click event in my webdriver testcase(like driver.findElement(elementToClick)).click(); it implicitly fires lots of mouse over event on menu bar before click. It sometimes troubles when populated dropdown menu comes in front of elementToClicked, as it clicks on menuitem present in front of element to be clicked.
Any Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you positive that that situation couldn't happen IRL? because if it can't why change the test?

Comment: I faced the problem while clicking a imagelink. a menuitem came came in front of that image and webdriver clicked on that image. As a workaround i explicitly fired moveToElement(toSomeOtherElement) to keep mouse away from that populated dropdown menu before clicking on that image.

Comment: I meant if it can happen in real life (not can't)

Comment: Yes it happened to my test case.

Comment: @RuneFS As a user you see what happened an you can correct your action- Selenium does what you tell it to do (mostly ;)

Comment: @Frank yes of course but the wording indicated that this was some thing that happened sometimes in which case the correct action would be to resolve that indeterminism not "hide" it from the tests. However the comments indicate that it was just a poorly recorded test which of course makes it a'ok to correct ;)

Comment: I have not mentioned anywhere but InternetExplorerDriver do not fire any such unnecessary mouse overs before click, it only fires events mentioned in testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
Action hover = actions.moveToElement(myWebElement).build();
hover.perform();
```

Only hovers the WebElement myWebElement

Comment: Thanks this worked I did something like:Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
Action hover = actions.moveToElement(anotherElementFarFromDesired).build();
hovering.perform();

Comment: @Akarsh if this worked for you, make sure to click the check mark next to the answer so others can quickly see that this is a working solution.